# Can a C extension class to pretend to be a Python list

Tags: python, cpython

I am working on embedding Python in another language, and want classes (e.g. `LIST`) from that language, that implement `COLLECTION` interface to be able to pretend to be `list` objects. That includes passing `isinstance(x, list)` check for maximum compatibility with poorly written Python code. (Let the God forgive me for this)

What is the best way to do so?

So far I've been adding mixins, that implement interfaces from `collections.abc` as extra base classes to the Python wrappers for `COLLECTION`-dervied types. However, that does not solve the `isinstance(x, list)` problem.

What issues pretending to be a `list` subclass might have, apart from forgetting to override some `list` members?

Comment: Can you provde a short example both of the extension and Python code? I'm not sure I completely understand what you mean by "classes from that language". Usually you return a Python object (using the C Python types) from the wrapper. If you are wrapping an actual class with `extern`, than the answer would be no.

Comment: Don't write a bad interface just to fit bad code. You'll just create even more problems that way.

Comment: ... Perhaps this is the an XY question? Why would you want to hide the fact you are not using an actual list? In any case, an example of code with the the usage point would go along way for the question.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica to understand the trade-off it would be good to know the list of potential problems.

Comment: All the stuff that actually needs a list, stuff that calls `list` methods directly or accesses the list memory layout at C level, will fail. Best case, it throws an exception, or it falls back to non-list code. Worst case, it thinks it's got a real list, and it immediately sets about corrupting memory.

Comment: @kabanus in order for Python to be able to call back every class in the other language, I create an adapter Python type, that forwards all calls back to the original class. Generally adapter has the same members as non-Python class, but I also map similar concepts (e.g. `COLLECTION` interface gets adapter to implement `collections.abc.Collection`).

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica "stuff that calls list methods directly or accesses the list memory layout at C level" - would not this only likely to happen if the class pretends to be exactly `list`, not a subclass?

Comment: Nope. Plenty of stuff accesses `list` internals directly even for subclasses.

Comment: @kabanus see for example this change: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/8fda6dd70398d77a9f8bc3a02d28bd0c0d37d52a . If properly coded, it would check if `layers` is `Iterable`. However, it is not, so `List[Layer]` has to be a subclass of `list` to work.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Python itself seems to be OK with subclassing `list` and overriding `__getitem__`, so it is a trade-off as I said.

See https://gist.github.com/lostmsu/6d53e5340319a85e45db01857cc6ed61

Comment: You can subclass `list` and override `__getitem__`, but the result will have a memory layout compatible with `list`. Anything that needs the `list` internals will find them. If you take your own object with an incompatible memory layout and pretend it's a `list` anyway, that all collapses.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica just got a hint about your point being important by trying to do `class MyList(str, list)` and getting "TypeError: multiple bases have instance lay-out conflict"